# JBoss fuse camel: Error when I evaluate a body

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am invoking a web service from the camel, and when I try to evaluate its response, I get an error. This is the camel code:

```
   <!-- Transformatio to the ws backend -->
        <process id="_transformToValidaAccesoUsuario" ref="transformToValidaAccesoUsuario"/>
        <!-- Invoke the ws -->
        <to id="invokeAutenticaSesion" uri="cxf:bean:autenticaSesionProxy?defaultOperationName=validarAccesoUsuario"/>
        <!-- Validate the response -->
        <choice id="validacionAutenticaUsuario">
            <when id="validacionUsuarioOK">
                <simple>${body.getResponseStatus.getDescripcionRespuesta} == 'OK'</simple>
                <log id="logValidacionUsuario" message="validacionUsuario correcto"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise id="validacionUsuarioError">
                <log id="logValidacionUsuario2" message="validacionUsuario incorrecto"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
```

I have this error when I run the service:

```
<faultstring>Failed to invoke method: getResponseStatus on null due to: org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Method with name: getResponseStatus not found on bean: [pe.gob.sis.esb.negocio.consultaafiliados.proxy.autenticasesion.ValidarAccesoUsuarioResponseType@f482049] of type: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList. Exchange[]</faultstring>
```

Edit:
The class already has the method getResponseStatus()

```
package pe.gob.sis.esb.negocio.consultaafiliados.proxy.autenticasesion;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ValidarAccesoUsuarioResponseType", namespace = "http://sis.gob.pe/esb/tecnico/autenticaSesion/messages/validarAccesoUsuario/v1/", propOrder = {
"responseStatus",
"login"
})
public class ValidarAccesoUsuarioResponseType {

    protected ResponseStatus responseStatus;
    protected Login login;

    public ResponseStatus getResponseStatus() {
        return responseStatus;
    }

    public void setResponseStatus(ResponseStatus value) {
        this.responseStatus = value;
    }

    public Login getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(Login value) {
        this.login = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong, your POJO class does not have that method you attempt to call

Comment: The class already has the method, I edited the question with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah its maybe the crappy `MessageContentsList` from camel-cxf / CXF. Its a design fault in camel-cxf I think. So what you can do is to convert the message body to not include that, by

```
<setBody><simple>${body[0]}</simple></setBody>
```

Which will take the first element from that `MessageContentsList` and store that as the message body, which will be that POJO class.

It depends a bit how you configure camel-cxf / CXF and what is stored as the message body. But the `MessageContentsList` is a smell.